# display json dictionary values in templates

Tags: django, json, django-templates, django-views, django-1.3

I am doing ajax using jquery in django1.3,well its works fine. Am using jquery load method to fill a  in a template.

I get a json object asychrosily when user cliks in a button.I pass it to another template(which i loading inside the div of first template ) as a dictionary. But am unaware of how I display it in template.(I tried to pasres json in template page),but its leads to error.
    Can any one suggest How can solve the problem?

So I used normal way parse json in view and pass it to template by using the method locals() in render_to_response(). Is it a good approch?

```
testjqyery.html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#save').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();         
        $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url t %}'  );            
    });
    <div id="results"></div>
```

views.py

```
def testupdater(request):
// getting json from server
//contents_json = json.loads(...)
json_data = {'json_dict': contents_json}
return render_to_response( 'results.html' ,json_data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

results.html

```
{% if json_dict|length %}

{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you're rendering the template server-side, why do you need the JSON at all? Just pass a normal context dictionary containing all your variables.

Comment: you are right @ Daniel Roseman,Thanks 4 u r comment

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
from django.utils import simplejson

data = []
data.append({"msg": 'Hi this message'})
json = simplejson.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: The problem is I got a large json from server,Hence its difficult to parse it in view and add to dictionary with a key manualy